# How can I parse a line by new lines and colons?

Tags: python, regex, split

I have text like [this](http://dpaste.org/hy5Kd/). I want to split by `New Line` and `Colons`. Right now I'm splitting by `New Lines`.I'm using this code.

```
`data= data.split('\n')
```

and Its giving [strange output](http://dpaste.org/8n9HD/). Can you please help? thanks

Comment: That's not strange at all. It's doing _exactly_ what you ask.

Comment: @Matt Ball Why its displaying `\t\t\t\t\t`.? I also tried `stip()` but not luck.

Comment: Because you must have a lot of tab characters in your input file.

Comment: Example text is not available anymore...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\t are tabs. To clean things a bit, try this:

```
data = [line.strip().split(':') for line in data.split('\n') if line.strip()]
```

it will remove empty lines and strip whitespaces

Comment: @Simon I've removed the `.split(':')`. So the result is `['Artist(s):', 'Music: Ramana Gogula']`. Now Can I read the value of `artist(s)` and `music`? thanks

Answer (score 7):

It's doing just what you're asking, but it's full of tabs.  Remove the tabs via `strip()`:

```
lines = data.split('\n')
lines = [line.strip() for line in lines]
```

and you should see something more like what you're expecting.

That will still leave some blank lines, so maybe you'll want to strip those too:

```
lines = filter(None, lines)
```

Answer (score 3):

How is your output strange? I mean, there's lots of tabulations `\t` and white spaces, but could you explain what does not suit your need?

Maybe you could `.strip()` lines first: this will remove blank spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The [str.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method only accepts a single splitter.  This precludes splitting on either a colon or a newline.  You can overcome this limitation with something like:

```
data = data.replace(':', '\n').split('\n')   # split on newlines and colons
```

You can also try the [re.split()](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.split) function for more fine grained control over splitting:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'abc:def\nghi'
>>> re.split(r'\:|\n', s)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
data = list(
    line.strip().split(":") for line in data.split("\n")
)

data = filter(None, data)
```

EDIT: Simon's answer will produce the same result while being a "cleaner" solution.

```
data = list(
    line.strip().split(":") for line in data.split("\n") if line.strip()
)
```